# Backbone collection 0.9.9 - add event not work

Tags: backbone.js

Backbone collection 0.9.9 - add event not work
After update backbone to 0.9.9, i have a problem with (add).

```
(function () {


var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('initialize Model');
    }
});


var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Model,
    url: "/json.json",

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('initialize Collection');
    }
});

var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        console.log('initialize View');
    }
});


var collection = new Collection([
    {
        "id"    : "001",
        "name"  : "Дарья",
        "text"  : "1 Вопрос - Ответ 1"
    }
]);

collection.on('add', function () {
    console.log('edd event', this)
});

collection.fetch({
    add: true,
    //silent: false,
    success: function (model) {
        console.log('fetch')
    }
});


}());
```

console.log('edd event', this) - not work (
in old versions it works

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the `add` option to `collection.fetch` is no longer supported.

From 0.9.2 source (collection.fetch):

```
collection[options.add ? 'add' : 'reset'](collection.parse(resp, xhr), options);
```

From 0.9.9 source (collection.fetch):

```
var method = options.update ? 'update' : 'reset';
collection[method](resp, options);
if (success) success(collection, resp, options);
```

So by default `collection.fetch` will cause a reset on the collection, and the `reset`event will be fired. If you pass option `update:true`, and `update` will be performed.

According to [documentation for the new collection.update method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-update), update will trigger the `add` events for added models, so the following should work:

```
collection.fetch({
    update: true,
    success: function (model) {
        console.log('fetch')
    }
});
```

Just test and be aware, that the new update method will also trigger `remove` and `change`events, if models are removed or changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the commented out line because it won't propagate the add events otherwise (see line 827 of the backbone.js source).  So the following should work

```
collection.fetch({
    add: true,
    silent: false,
    success: function (model) {
        console.log('fetch')
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if that's a change from previous versions :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather from checking out the Backbone 0.9.9 source, the `add` -option does nothing  with `fetch` unless you add in the `update` - option as well. [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-100)

So to do something useful with it do the following:

```
collection.fetch({
    add: true,
    update: true, // this is necessary as well
    //silent: false,
    success: function (model) {
        console.log('fetch')
    }
});
```

This is also the cause for your problem. When you fetch, the `Collection` automatically defaults to the `reset` -function after fetching. `reset` silences the `add` -events and opts to just trigger a `reset` event as is evident from the Backbone.js [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-105)

```
if (models) this.add(models, _.extend({silent: true}, options));
```

So use the `update` option if you want the `add` -events and do not want to empty the collection before adding the new models. If you must have the reset functionality AND the `add` event, then you might have to write some custom implementation of `reset`.

Comment: I don't think `add: true` does anything but I could be wrong. The `update: true` is certainly correct though. Looks like an option renaming in 0.9.9.

Comment: Also add a `remove: true` to prevent the models to be removed when data being pulled. I have tested, the equivalent from the good old `add: true` is `update: true, remove: false`